# How to swap individual elements in a list with a foor loop?

Tags: python

So I'm writing a function that takes 2 lists and switches their values. I'll have 2 lists

```
list_one = [1, 2, 3]
list_two = [4, 5, 6]
```

and I want to switch their values. The output should look something like

```
#Before swap
list_one: [1, 2, 3]
list_two: [4, 5, 6]



#After swap
list_one: [4, 5, 6]
list_two: [1, 2, 3]
```

This is a little school assignment so I'd like to use a for loop which is what it says I need.

Here's my code so far:

```
def swap_lists(first, second):
    if len(first) != len(second):
        print "Lengths must be equal!"
        return
    first == second
    print second

list_one = [1, 2, 3]
list_two = [4, 5, 6]
print "Before swap"
print "list_one: " + str(list_one)
print "list_two: " + str(list_two)
swap_lists(list_one, list_two)
print "After swap"
print "list_one: " + str(list_one)
print "list_two: " + str(list_two)
```

I've also figured out that

```
first,second = second,first
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Just FYI: `first, second = second[:], first[:]` works. Doesn't have a for loop, but is concise.

Comment: Why do you use the `[:]`? What do they mean?

Comment: it also works for lists of unequal length, no need for for-loops

Comment: @exfizik I think you mean `first[:], second[:] = second[:], first[:]`, although that's only necessary if you want to do this in a function and you want to mutate the lists that were passed in.

Comment: @akraf `some_list[:]` means a copy of `some_list`

Comment: first == second by the way should return true or false as it is a boolean operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as a `for` loop you can swap element by element

```
for i in range(len(list_one)):
    list_one[i], list_two[i] = list_two[i], list_one[i]
```

More concisely you can swap the whole lists

```
list_one, list_two = list_two, list_one
```

You'd need extra logic in either of the above methods if one list is longer than the other

Comment: I do not think that you  need extra logic in your second method, if one list is longer than the other. For me, `a=[1,2]; b=[1,2,3]; a,b=b,a` works perfectly fine?

Comment: `list_one, list_two = list_two, list_one` *will not work* in a function, at least, the changes will not be visible to the caller, which would make for a pretty useless swap function, since Python lacks call-by-reference semantics

Answer (score 1):

In addition to CoryKramer's answer, for easy understanding, you can use a temporary variable:

```
def swap_lists(first, second):
    if len(first) != len(second):
        print "Lengths must be equal!"
        return
    for i in range(0, len(first)):
        temp = second[i]
        second[i] = first[i]
        first[i] = temp

list_one = [1, 2, 3]
list_two = [4, 5, 6]

print "Before swap"
print "list_one: " + str(list_one)
print "list_two: " + str(list_two)

swap_lists(list_one, list_two)

print "After swap"
print "list_one: " + str(list_one)
print "list_two: " + str(list_two)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 def swap_values(list_one, list_two):
     if len(list_one) != len(list_two)
         raise NotImplementedError("Invalid list sizes for swap")
     for i in range(len(list_one)):
         list_one[i], list_two[i] = list_two[i], list_one[i]
```

There are better ways to do this, but if you have to use a for loop this is a fairly compact way that addresses mismatched lengths.

If you need logic for handling mismatched lengths, insert it where appropriate and remove the NotImplementedError

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both lists are of equal length:

```
 def swap_lists(first, second):
    if len(first) != len(second):
        print "Lengths must be equal!"
        return
    for idx, val in enumerate(first):
        temp = first[idx]
        first[idx] = second[idx]
        second[idx] = temp
```

If your assignment is asking for a for loop, it's so you work with iterating over the **indexes** of the lists.

So I don't feel bad for answering for answering a homework question, here is the usual disclaimer to make sure you understand whatever you turn in, be it my solution or another answer here. I'd also read about Python's [enumerate](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/) function, which I used above.

Answer (score 0):

Python provide very nice way to swap element just use :

```
list_one = [1, 2, 3]
list_two = [4, 5, 6]


for i in range(len(list_one)):
    for j in range(len(list_two)):
        list_one[i],list_two[j]=list_two[j],list_one[i]

print("old list  : {} is now swapped list : {}".format(list_one,list_two))

print("old list  : {} is now swapped list : {}".format(list_two,list_one))
```